# KML: calculate Range from bounding coordinates in Python

Tags: python, range, kml, bounding-box

Having the bounding box coordinates of a certain polygon, is there a way with Python to calculate the ideal Range-value for the LookAt-element in a KML-file?

A formula or set of formulas to get from the bounding coordinates to the Range, would already be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a kml file, you can skip the LookAt element. Google Earth will default the values when you doubleclick the according item. Try to save your file then again from GE, it is likely to have the defaults for the lookat saved.

If you want to set it by yourself, range is the distance from the point specified by lat/lon/alt. It is well illustrated at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#lookat). The figure there explains it, no neaf for a formula.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do this with a script instead of saving it in GE. I have a lot of KMZ's and most of them open correctly in GE. However for some of them GE looks at the wrong location when the files are opened in GE. Therefore I want to include a LookAt element in the KML-files, but don't know how to determine the Range.

Answer (score 0):

Given your boundaries are x1,y1,x2,y2
then the range can be computed by the following routine

```
R = 6371 # radius of earth
domain_width = R*np.cos(abs(y1+y2)*np.pi/360.0)*(x2-x1)*np.pi/180.0
dist_factor = 2  # factor by which height should exceed width
range = min([1000*dist_factor*domain_width,9656064.0])
```